# How to login with Google Account? (error: popup_closed_by_user)

Tags: javascript, laravel, google-chrome, google-signin

I am trying to log in with google account on my website but I am getting the error:

> popup_closed_by_user

```
// Render Google Sign-in button
function renderButton() {
  gapi.signin2.render('gSignIn', {
    'scope': 'profile email',
    'plugin_name':'abcd01233',
    'width': 240,
    'height': 50,
    'longtitle': true,
    'theme': 'dark',
    'onsuccess': onSuccess,
    'onfailure': onFailure
  });
}

// Sign-in success callback
function onSuccess(googleUser) {
    // Get the Google profile data (basic)
    //var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();

    // Retrieve the Google account data
    gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function() {
        var request = gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get({
            'userId': 'me'
        });
        request.execute(function(resp) {
            // Display the user details
            var profileHTML = '<h3>Welcome ' + resp.given_name +
                '! <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a></h3>';
            profileHTML += '<img src="' + resp.picture + '"/><p><b>Google ID: </b>' + resp.id +
                '</p><p><b>Name: </b>' + resp.name + '</p><p><b>Email: </b>' + resp.email +
                '</p><p><b>Gender: </b>' + resp.gender + '</p><p><b>Locale: </b>' + resp.locale +
                '</p><p><b>Google Profile:</b> <a target="_blank" href="' + resp.link +
                '">click to view profile</a></p>';
            document.getElementsByClassName("userContent")[0].innerHTML = profileHTML;

            document.getElementById("gSignIn").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementsByClassName("userContent")[0].style.display = "block";

            // Save user data
            saveUserData(resp);
        });
    });
}


// Sign-in failure callback
function onFailure(error) {
    console.log(error);
    alert(error);
}

// Sign out the user
function signOut() {
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth2.signOut().then(function() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("userContent")[0].innerHTML = '';
        document.getElementsByClassName("userContent")[0].style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("gSignIn").style.display = "block";
    });

    auth2.disconnect();
}
// Save user data to the database
function saveUserData(userData) {
    $.post("saveData.php", {
        oauth_provider: 'google',
        userData: JSON.stringify(userData)
    });
}
```

Comment: Where did you get that code from?   Have you tried the new web identity system?  [one tap](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/display-google-one-tap)  or are you trying to get authorization working as opposed to signin [javascript-implicit-flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use [Laravel socialite](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/socialite#configuration)? You can integrate Google and Facebook auths in less than 10 minutes.

Here is the full tutorial if you are not sure how to integrate it (google OAuth is shown but others can be done in the same way):
[Link for tutorial](https://codyrigg.medium.com/how-to-add-a-google-login-using-socialite-on-laravel-8-with-jetstream-6153581e7dc9)

Comment: Thanks for your response. there is a restriction of versions so I have to use in thus way

Comment: @SunnySaini Not sure if this will help but you can install older versions of the socialite. You just need to check which version you need. ```composer require laravel/socialite 2.0```